# Flash Builder With Java Integration

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

i am trying to build a desktop application that requires no run time, therefore Flash builder seems to be the only choice.

There is a Flash Builder and Java Integration as show [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flashbuilder4_datawizards_spring.html)
but it seems to be a server that is supporting it.
Its more applicable to website?

Is it feasible to do it , if i am building a desktop application?

Comment: Flash Builder is an IDE, a tool to help you write your program - there is no difference in the output it creates to any other compiled flash binary.  Both Java and Flash **always** need a virtual machine to run. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i am trying to code a desktop application that allows me to display my  computer images and make amendments to its metadata. Previously was working it with Javafx, but it does not run on normal java virtual machine. Therefore i thought of using Flash Builder and Java integration as my codes are in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash Builder, if used to generate a desktop app,  will require Adobe AIR to be installed, which is a small runtime.  If you prefer, it can accessed as a website as well, which will require the flash player be installed.

Flex, the language used by Flash Builder, has to be able to connect to Java somehow.  You can use SOAP objects, BlazeDS, JSON, HTTP or even PHP/JavaBridge combo (Zend Server Community Server and PHP 5.3 have one).

The point is, there has to be an accessible server somewhere with JAR files on it. How you get to it is totally up to you.

For more FlashBuilder & Flex info, I recommend http://adobe.com/devnet/flex

Comment: Yeah , there is a tutorial on Flex & Java Integration here [link](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flashbuilder4_datawizards_spring.html)

but it seems to be more suitable to be implemented for web server client application rather than a desktop application. Am i right ?

Comment: I'm a little confused on your goal. If you are trying to run Java code locally - no, Flash Builder needs Flex. FB/Flex can run just locally. Tweetdeck uses Flex, and connects via api's. A lot of phone apps also use it. It will do ajax calls to connect to server for data, but only as you need.  The java in this example sits on the EE side of things.

Answer (score 0):

Java require a VM to run, so there might not be a way to do it without one.